How to share a single gain resistor among multiple op-amps in a circuit
I'm currently designing a circuit where I need to implement multiple op-amps, each configured with the same variable gain resistor using a single digital potentiometer.
To simplify the design and reduce component count, I'd like to use the same gain resistor (which is a digital potentiometers in my case) across all op-amps. However, I'm unsure about the best approach to achieve this.
Here is my drawing:

From my understanding, instrumentation amplifiers share a single gain resistor (R1 in the picture below) with two input buffers in the first stage before feeding into a differential amplifier (green box):

Image source: Electronics Tutorials - High Input Impedance Instrumentation Amplifier
This is exactly what I need, but I couldn't find any way to extend this configuration for more than 2 op-amps (I need for 4 op-amps at the moment).
I'm wondering if there are any techniques or best practices for ensuring that the gain resistor is properly matched and that the gain remains consistent across all op-amps.
If anyone has experience or insights into efficiently using the same gain resistor among multiple op-amps, I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions.

My hacked solution:

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=NoNgQpbj77Y&ab_channel=EngineeringProf
Use one of these circuits, you should be able to parallel the current mirror. by doing this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Simulate it and see if it's a solution for your application.

Hi, that's actually a good solution, one question thought, considering that gain won't change too often and will remain constant ... is there any possibility that transistors cause noise to output signal?

Yeah, and distortion, they are kind of like a variable resistor at that point. Another thing is you'll need well matched transistors or have a way to calibrate them. I haven't done too many current mirrors but this is worth experimenting with. If you like the soution please use the voting system.

pardon my inability to uptove as I don't have minimum reputation but this is pretty much what I'm looking for so I'll accept as answer

The instrumentation amp single-resistor gain set works because both input amps are processing aspects of the same signal.  You want to have currents from four different signals go through one resistor (capacitor, inductor, digi-pot - whatever) without interacting, and that won't work.
If you use integrated programmable gain amplifiers, then you can send the same binary code to all four of them while maintaining complete isolation of the four inputs and four outputs.  This is a minor variation of having four digi-pots and four opamps.

Hi, thanks for pointing that out, unfortunately PGAs are hard to find (here) and that's why I'm forced to find an alternative for my current project
